# Code Signing install.exe with own Issued to field

Tags: windows-server-2008

Today I've tried to sign my install.exe file with certificate. I created csr (certificate sign request) file (on linux machine), and tried to generate certificate by RootCA (Active Directory) on Windows Server 2008 R2. I opened CMD as administrator, run:

```
certreq -submit -attrib "CertificateTemplate:CodeSigning" request.csr
```

and saved new certificate. The problem is that the new cert's field "Issued to" is my name

I signed my install.exe with this cert,run install.exe file and the pop up window (Windows allert about untrusted application) printed: "Issued to: _my_name_"

Is it possible to generate this cert with "Issued to: My Company Name" ?

Thanks for help!
Gary

Comment: and how ssl-certificate tag is related to your question?

Answer (score 1):

you need to duplicate a default Code Signing template (by selecting Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition in the compatibility dialog) and changing subject name construction in the Subject Name tab. Switch radiobutton to "Supply in the request" as in the following example:
[image]

However, I would strongly recommend carefully inspect each incoming request for this template.